# boot stuck on "load/save rf kill switch status"

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I recently tried to install lubuntu on an old computer. After a successful install I installed updates however and restarted. But when the computer booted again I saw only a black screen.

After following the instructions here: 
[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) 
I edited grub menu to start OS with nomodeset.

The problem is that now while booting the computer is stuck on 
`[OK] started load/save RF kill switch status`

The computer is an inspiron mini 1018

Any ideas?

Comment: What lubuntu version you tried? 18.04 lts, 19.10?

Comment: Try pressing Fn+F2 in order to turn on/off the wi-fi  and then reboot. The idea is to test if the reboot gets stuck there in both cases (with wifi on and off).

Comment: I would boot with `quiet splash` removed from your 'linux' kernel line as well; so you see more messages and see if more detail shows. I would also like have it stop booting at runlevel 1 so I could explore, even review what you last did to see if there's a reason for your issue. Have you tried using older kernels? (ie. selecting them from grub) but I'd want to know your Lubuntu release first (I don't know if you're using LXQt, LXDE, calamares/ubiquity installed  and what software stack you're using yet)

Comment: @Gryu 18.04, I also reinstalled so I have not updated beyond that.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I tried, no luck, same results.

Comment: @guiverc i booted withput quiet splash but I couldn't see any more messages. 
If you could please elaborate about the rest I would appreciate it. I'm new to this.
The grub doesn't offer any older kernels, only Linux 4.15.0-20-generic and recovery mode.
I am using Lubuntu from Lubuntu.net so I believe it is LXDE

Comment: Lubuntu.net is not a site managed by either Lubuntu, or Ubuntu.  If you're unsure where to download a Ubuntu flavor, ask ubuntu.com (not google.com which offers many choices that aren't our sites) where ubuntu.com will show you to https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours and the official Lubuntu site.  To enter runlevel 1, as well as removing 'quiet splash' you add a ' 1 ' to the kernel line ('linux' line).  It will stop processing when it reaches run level 1 (normal is 5) so you'll have a root terminal only. My hope is this would let you view boot logs, peruse systemd logs etc.. for clues.

Comment: You mentioned you're "*new to this*" so I haven't provided enough to be of real benefit.   If it was me I'd look at where your download occurred from, if it was ubuntu.com (ie. the unofficial site referred had you download an official ISO) it'll be okay, if it provided it itself I would start again with an official ISO (I believe it'll be okay from lubuntu.net as managed by an ex-Lubuntu leader). The OK line that printed is the last 'good' line and not your problem, it's what's next you'll hopefully see via root terminal (but what I lack time for now)

Comment: Try disabling Wi-Fi from BIOS (lowest level possible...) to see if it is blocking the boot process

Comment: This is a stab in the dark, but what happens if you add the kernel boot parameter *systemd.mask=tlp.service*? That *should* stop the rfkill.status and let you boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing dual-boot so you have to install first Ubuntu and then other OS.
and if you are installing only Ubuntu so first format the disk and then make memory partitions allocate boot-files memory then install Ubuntu.